# Spring Security Core Plugin 2.0-RC2 upgrade issue?

Tags: grails, spring-security, upgrade, deprecated

I have a grails project and I just upgraded my Spring Security Core plugin to the latest version however I get the following message when trying to run the app:

```
| Error Compilation error: startup failed:
Compile error during compilation with javac.
/home/dev/.grails/2.1.0/projects/app/plugins/spring-security-ldap-1.0.6/src/java/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/plugins/springsecurity/ldap/DatabaseOnlyLdapAuthoritiesPopulator.java:20: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class GrailsUserDetailsService
location: package org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.GrailsUserDetailsService;
                                                        ^
/home/dev/.grails/2.1.0/projects/app/plugins/spring-security-ldap-1.0.6/src/java/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/plugins/springsecurity/ldap/DatabaseOnlyLdapAuthoritiesPopulator.java:37: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class GrailsUserDetailsService
location: class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.DatabaseOnlyLdapAuthoritiesPopulator
    private GrailsUserDetailsService _userDetailsService;
            ^
/home/dev/.grails/2.1.0/projects/app/plugins/spring-security-ldap-1.0.6/src/java/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/plugins/springsecurity/ldap/DatabaseOnlyLdapAuthoritiesPopulator.java:71: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class GrailsUserDetailsService
location: class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.DatabaseOnlyLdapAuthoritiesPopulator
    public void setUserDetailsService(final GrailsUserDetailsService service) {
                                            ^
/home/dev/.grails/2.1.0/projects/app/plugins/spring-security-ldap-1.0.6/src/java/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/plugins/springsecurity/ldap/GrailsLdapAuthoritiesPopulator.java:20: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class GrailsUserDetailsService
location: package org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.GrailsUserDetailsService;
                                                        ^
/home/dev/.grails/2.1.0/projects/app/plugins/spring-security-ldap-1.0.6/src/java/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/plugins/springsecurity/ldap/GrailsLdapAuthoritiesPopulator.java:36: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class GrailsUserDetailsService
location: class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.GrailsLdapAuthoritiesPopulator
    private GrailsUserDetailsService _userDetailsService;
            ^
/home/dev/.grails/2.1.0/projects/app/plugins/spring-security-ldap-1.0.6/src/java/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/plugins/springsecurity/ldap/GrailsLdapAuthoritiesPopulator.java:147: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class GrailsUserDetailsService
location: class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.GrailsLdapAuthoritiesPopulator
    public void setUserDetailsService(final GrailsUserDetailsService service) {
                                            ^
/home/dev/.grails/2.1.0/projects/app/plugins/spring-security-ldap-1.0.6/src/java/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/plugins/springsecurity/ldap/GrailsLdapUserDetailsManager.java:3: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class GrailsUserDetailsService
location: package org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.GrailsUserDetailsService;
                                                        ^
/home/dev/.grails/2.1.0/projects/app/plugins/spring-security-ldap-1.0.6/src/java/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/plugins/springsecurity/ldap/GrailsLdapUserDetailsManager.java:13: cannot find symbol
symbol: class GrailsUserDetailsService
public class GrailsLdapUserDetailsManager extends LdapUserDetailsManager implements GrailsUserDetailsService {
                                                                                    ^
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
8 errors
```

Can someone please help with this?

Thanks

---

***EDIT*************

---

I have now gone through the plugins and core files and made sure all new Spring Security imports are correct. The app now compiles fine however when I run it and try to access the home page I get the following errors:

```
| Running Grails application

Configuring Spring Security UI ...
... finished configuring Spring Security UI

Configuring Spring Security Core ...
... finished configuring Spring Security Core
| Error 2014-03-10 11:44:51,598 [pool-7-thread-1] ERROR plugins.DefaultGrailsPluginManager  - Error configuring dynamic methods for plugin [springSecurityCore:2.0-RC2]: null
Message: null
   Line | Method
->> 308 | compileStaticRules        in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.access.intercept.AnnotationFilterInvocationDefinition
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   218 | initialize                in     ''
|   738 | initializeFromAnnotations in SpringSecurityCoreGrailsPlugin
|   599 | doCall                    in SpringSecurityCoreGrailsPlugin$_closure3
|   303 | innerRun . . . . . . . .  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
|   138 | run                       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   895 | runTask . . . . . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   918 | run                       in     ''
^   662 | run . . . . . . . . . . . in java.lang.Thread
| Server running. Browse to http://localhost:8080/my_app
| Error 2014-03-10 11:49:36,541 [http-bio-8080-exec-2] ERROR [/my_app].[gsp]  - Servlet.service() for servlet [gsp] in context with path [/my_app] threw exception
Message: null
   Line | Method
->> 273 | isAjax                          in grails.plugin.springsecurity.SpringSecurityUtils
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    45 | determineUrlToUseForThisRequest in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.AjaxAwareAuthenticationEntryPoint
|    53 | doFilter . . . . . . . . . . .  in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter
|    49 | doFilter                        in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter
|    82 | doFilter . . . . . . . . . . .  in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter
|   895 | runTask                         in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   918 | run . . . . . . . . . . . . . . in     ''
^   662 | run                             in java.lang.Thread
```

Can someone please offer any guidance on this?

Thanks

Comment: I did a grails clean and then restarted the project and all was fine :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have to upgrade to [spring-security-ldap plugin to 2.0-RC2](http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-ldap) in order to use Spring Security Core 2.0_RC2.

**Reason:**
Notice the [change in package name](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/userDetailsService.html) in latest version of security core plugin.

```
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.GrailsUserDetailsService
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userdetails.GrailsUserDetailsService
```

Answer (score 6):

Try cleaning all output artefacts

```
grails clean-all
```

Kill all java processes
Clear caches of your IDE and restart the IDE and retry.

I got this error when using Intellij Idea and ReflectionUtils class was having inconsistent behavior. Possibly a class caching issue.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that if you are using annotations, you need to provide an array of roles and no longer a single string:

@Secured(['IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY'])